# How can I pass an image into my code from the linux command line?

Tags: python, argv

I am trying to adapt some code to better suit my needs. The code currently takes all the files from a folder and runs image recognition on them, but I need to pass a single image that I specify from the command line.

Here is the code I am using:

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
# import the necessary packages
import json
import os
import random

import cv2 as cv
import keras.backend as K
import numpy as np
import scipy.io

from utils import load_model

if __name__ == '__main__':
    img_width, img_height = 224, 224
    model = load_model()
    model.load_weights('models/model.96-0.89.hdf5')

    cars_meta = scipy.io.loadmat('devkit/cars_meta')
    class_names = cars_meta['class_names']  # shape=(1, 196)
    class_names = np.transpose(class_names)

    test_path = 'data/test/'
    test_images = [f for f in os.listdir(test_path) if
                   os.path.isfile(os.path.join(test_path, f)) and f.endswith('.jpg')]

    num_samples = 1
    samples = random.sample(test_images, num_samples)
    results = []
    for i, image_name in enumerate(samples):
        filename = os.path.join(test_path, image_name)
        print('Start processing image: {}'.format(filename))
        bgr_img = cv.imread(filename)
        bgr_img = cv.resize(bgr_img, (img_width, img_height), cv.INTER_CUBIC)
        rgb_img = cv.cvtColor(bgr_img, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        rgb_img = np.expand_dims(rgb_img, 0)
        preds = model.predict(rgb_img)
        prob = np.max(preds)
        class_id = np.argmax(preds)
        text = ('Predict: {}, prob: {}'.format(class_names[class_id][0][0], prob))
        results.append({'label': class_names[class_id][0][0], 'prob': '{:.4}'.format(prob)})
        cv.imwrite('images/{}_out.png'.format(i), bgr_img)

    print(results)
    with open('results.json', 'w') as file:
        json.dump(results, file, indent=4)

    K.clear_session()
```

Is there a way that I can just pass a single image, instead of an entire folder, and do so from the command line?

Comment: you can just passit and use the sys.argv[] list or to import the argparse and and to use the method pars

Answer (score 1):

`sys.argv` is a list in Python, which contains the command-line arguments passed to the script.

pay attention `sys.argv[0]` is the name of the script itself!

so the easieaset way to do it is by the built in `sys.argv list`. for example if my script is called : `foo.py`, i can pass to it arguments via command line like so:

```
python foo.py "C:\user\myimg.jpeg"
```

and in foo.py ican get the passed argument like so:

```
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
        #do work with arg! arg is a string type!
        with open(arg) as fp:
            #.... do work ....
```

**argparse module**

The following code is a Python program that takes a list of integers and produces either the sum or the max:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')
parser.add_argument('integers', metavar='N', type=int, nargs='+',
                    help='an integer for the accumulator')
parser.add_argument('--sum', dest='accumulate', action='store_const',
                    const=sum, default=max,
                    help='sum the integers (default: find the max)')

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.accumulate(args.integers))
```

using or calling from command line:

```
python foo.py 1 2 3 4
output: 4

python foo.py 1 2 3 4 --sum
10
```